# Displaying more on each page with many ignored tags

Tags: feature-request

I like reading a lot of content on each page. I'd rather scroll than click a link to next page. I was therefore wondering if it's possible to increase the amount of questions on each page? The fact that i have a lot of ignored tags reduces each page to ~10 questions.

Comment: Did you use the `15 30 50 per page` link at the bottom to make it 50?

Comment: You could use a whitelist of favourite tags instead of a blacklist of ignored tags.

Comment: @AndrewC Yes. There should be buttons with higher values as well, imho.

Comment: That would be nice, yes, I agree.